# Is it possible to construct a consistent unstable one step method of order 2? why?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Is it possible to construct a consistent unstable one step method of order 2? why?

I think the answer is no but I have no clue to prove it. Can anyone give me some explanations? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO because for any consistent method the polynomial $\rho$ has the root 1. One-step methods have no other roots, which again highlights the fact that they are automatically 0-stable. 
You can see the answer in Ascher's book, Chapter 5, page 140.